# Calling a (helper) method from a view with two arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having problems with calling a (helper) method in a controller from a view.
I had a helper method which i simply called in a link_to but i had problems with that and i went to look for answers to this problem and i discovered that you cannot simply call a helper method from a view that way, so i tried to follow the recommendations of another answer but it's still not working.

I'm getting this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/pages/associateplace.5"
```

In the view (pages/associate_place_to_activity.html.erb) i have this:

```
<%= link_to "Choose Place", pages_associateplace_path(@activity.id, place.id), :class => 'btn btn-default btn-xs' %>
```

In the controller (pages_controller) i have this:

```
 def associateplace
    @activity_id = params[:activity_id]
    @place_id = params[:place_id]
    Activity.find(activityid).place_id=placeid
    redirect_to Activity.find(activityid)
  end
```

´
And in the routes.rb i have this:

```
put 'pages/associateplace/:activity_id/:place_id' => 'pages#associateplace', as: :associateplace
```

Comment: You didn't call it pages_associateplace. You called associateplace. So I guess in yout link_to you should take off the pages_ part and leave only: associateplace_path(@activity.id, place.id)  is that correct?

Comment: i get this error: No route matches [GET] "/pages/associateplace.5"

Comment: You have a `put` route and are sending a `get` request. Those should match up.

Comment: There is one more thing. You've created a PUT route. But in a link_to you need to specify that it is a PUT that you want since GET is the default. So you need to write:  <%= link_to "Choose Place", pages_associateplace_path(@activity.id, place.id), method: :put %>

Comment: I've posted the official answer! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't call it pages_associateplace. You called associateplace. So in your link_to you should take off the pages_ part and leave only: associateplace_path(@activity.id, place.id)

There is one more thing. You've created a PUT route. But in a link_to you need to specify that it is a PUT that you want since GET is the default. So you need to write:

```
<%= link_to "Choose Place", associateplace_path(@activity.id, place.id), method: :put %>
```